# How to create a dynamic divider / separator like JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsfiddle, flexbox

I'm working on developing layout for our project and wondering if you can recommend some approach to develop separator or divider which can change size of div's. I'm using CSS FlexBox for div layouts.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at jQueryUI, it has some nice features for dragging and resizing: http://jqueryui.com/resizable/

Comment: Could you show your (relevant) css and HTML?

Comment: This might be too broad. I doubt, you will get a complete answer.